# AWS EC2 instance launch error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am havving trouble to launch EC2 instance with particular user. The decoded error message (from aws sts decode-authorization-message) is:

```
DecodedMessage|{  
   "allowed":false,
   "explicitDeny":false,
   "matchedStatements":{  
      "items":[  

      ]
   },
   "failures":{  
      "items":[  

      ]
   },
   "context":{  
      "principal":{  
         "id":"AIDAJJEIJ6GU4IX5WT5DA",
         "name":"aws_portal",
         "arn":"arn:aws:iam::846575128002:user/aws_portal"
      },
      "action":"ec2:RunInstances",
      "resource":"arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1::image/ami-8282a2f1",
      "conditions":{  
         "items":[  
            {  
               "key":"ec2:ImageType",
               "values":{  
                  "items":[  
                     {  
                        "value":"machine"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"ec2:Owner",
               "values":{  
                  "items":[  
                     {  
                        "value":"846575128002"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"ec2:Public",
               "values":{  
                  "items":[  
                     {  
                        "value":"false"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"ec2:Region",
               "values":{  
                  "items":[  
                     {  
                        "value":"eu-west-1"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"ec2:RootDeviceType",
               "values":{  
                  "items":[  
                     {  
                        "value":"ebs"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
```

Does anyone know what the problem is - to be honest this message doesn't help me at all - I don't understand it

Comment: I believe it is saying that the user `arn:aws:iam::846575128002:user/aws_portal` doesn't have the `ec2:RunInstances` permission.

Comment: It has ec2:RunInstance permissions - for instance, ami, volume, snapshot...